# Input value not working with autocomplete plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to print db values to an input field that the plugin auto-generates. The value is added to the select list but it's supposed to be copied to the input field. The plugin is [selectToAutocomplete](https://github.com/JamieAppleseed/selectToAutocomplete)

This is the jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#countries, #cities").selectToAutocomplete({
        'copy-attributes-to-text-field': true
    });
    var $getCountry = $("select option[value='<?php print $client->getCountry(); ?>']").text();
    $("#countries").val($getCountry);
});
```

And this is a normal select list:

```
<select id="countries" name="client_info[6]" placeholder="Country">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="abc">ABC</option>
    <option value="123">123</option>
</select><br>
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the option name with jquery and print it in the input field. But it seems this plugin doesn't accept the value attribute.

Is there any way to make it work?

Thanks!

Edit: Add jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v1mf7waw/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The plugin doesn't copy attributes after creating the text field so using the class name of the input to set the value:

```
var $getCountry = $("select option[value='<?php print $client->getCountry(); ?>']").text();
$(".ui-autocomplete-input").val($getCountry);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#countries, #cities").selectToAutocomplete({
    'copy-attributes-to-text-field': true
});
var $getCountry = $("select").val();
$("#countries").val($getCountry);
```

});

EDIT: understood now:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JamieAppleseed/selectToAutocomplete/master/jquery.select-to-autocomplete.js"></script>

<select id="countries" name="client_info[6]" placeholder="Country">
<option <?php if($client->getCountry() == "")echo "selected=selected"; ?>  value=""></option>
<option <?php if($client->getCountry() == "abc")echo "selected=selected"; ?> value="abc">ABC</option>
<option <?php if($client->getCountry() == "123")echo "selected=selected"; ?> value="123">123</option>
</select><br>
```

Comment: where is the input? there is only a select field. I think I now understand the cuestion, but there's no need for jquery

Comment: Hmm but that's a lot of code. Maybe using jquery to set the attribute like this: $("select option[value='abc']").attr("selected", "selected"); But this is not working...